# Background image stays even when class is toggled

Tags: jquery, css, sass

I'm not sure how to explain this properly but this should function as a regular read more button toggling both the text and the image (icon). However, for some reason toggling the class does not remove one of the images while it works for the other so one of the 2 images is always visible.

This is the html

```
 <div class="read-more more">
   <button class="read-more_button">Read more</button>
 </div>
```

And this is the jQuery I used to toggle the class of the read more div. It always starts off with the class "more".

```
$(".read-more").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("more less");
  $(".content-sidebar").toggleClass("longtext");

  if( $(this).hasClass("less") ) {
    $(".read-more_button").html("Hide");
  } else if( $(this).hasClass("more") ) {
    $(".read-more_button").html("Read more");
  }
});
```

EDIT: And this is the css (sass) used to add the icons

```
.read-more {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;

  &.more {
    background: (gradient but removed for readability)

    button.read-more_button {
      background: url('assets/plus-more.png') 0 / 14px no-repeat transparent;
    } 
  }

  &.less {
    background: transparent;

    button.read-more_button {
      background: url('assets/minus-less.png') 0 / 14px no-repeat transparent;
    }
  }

  button.read-more_button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 30px;
    right: 30px;
    border: none;
    background: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 20px;
    color: $gray-dark;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
  }
}
```

Both classes have an icon set as background image. "more" has a plus icon and "less" a minus icon. The icon for "less" works as it should. For "more" this is not the case. The plus icon stays visible even when class "more" has been toggled to "less". How can I make it so that both the plus and minus icon only show when their class is active?

Comment: We also need to see the associated CSS

Comment: Gotcha, added the CSS

Comment: Using an online SCSS compiler, and replacing the images, this works fine:  https://jsfiddle.net/vpf2sgao/   can you provide the compiled css?  Also works with SCSS in the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/vpf2sgao/1/ - could it be something with the `background: (gradient but removed)`?  Try your code with that whole line removed.

Comment: The gradient is just a standard css gradient and its fallbacks which is set to the background of the wrapper not the button itself. I just noticed though that the icon does change on different pages. It uses the exact same code but the content is different. Strange.